# NSTimer doesn't call method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstimer

I'm really frustrated now, googled the whole internet, stumbled through SO and still didn't find a solution.

I'm trying to implement an NSTimer, but the method which I defined doesn't get called. (seconds are set correctly, checked it with breakpoints). Here is the code:

```
- (void) setTimerForAlarm:(Alarm *)alarm {
    NSTimeInterval seconds = [[alarm alarmDate] timeIntervalSinceNow];
    theTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:seconds 
                            target:self 
                          selector:@selector(showAlarm:)
                          userInfo:alarm repeats:NO];
}

- (void) showAlarm:(Alarm *)alarm {
    NSLog(@"Alarm: %@", [alarm alarmText]);
}
```

The object "theTimer" is deined with @property:

```
@interface FooAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSWindowDelegate>  {
@private

    NSTimer *theTimer;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *theTimer;

- (void) setTimerForAlarm:(Alarm *)alarm;
- (void) showAlarm:(Alarm *)alarm;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The method signature for `showAlarm:(Alarm *)alarm` should be `showAlarm:(NSTimer *)timer` instead. Then you would get the Alarm object with `Alarm *alarm = [timer userInfo]`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

timerWithTimeInterval simply creates a timer, but doesn't add it to any run loops for execution. Try

```
self.theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:seconds 
                        target:self 
                      selector:@selector(showAlarm:)
                      userInfo:alarm repeats:NO];
```

instead.

Answer (score 8):

Also don't forget to check if

```
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds 
                                     target:(id)target 
                                   selector:(SEL)aSelector 
                                   userInfo:(id)userInfo 
                                    repeats:(BOOL)repeats
```

is called in the main thread.

Comment: this is really important! it was the cause for my timer not firing

Answer (score 7):

You've created an NSTimer object but you haven't scheduled it to be run. timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats: creates a timer that you can schedule to run later, for example, to create a timer at application launch and have it start counting when the user presses a button. Either call

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:theTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode]
```

at the end of setTimerForAlarm or replace

```
theTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:seconds 
                            target:self 
                          selector:@selector(showAlarm:)
                          userInfo:alarm repeats:NO];
```

with

```
theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:seconds 
                            target:self 
                          selector:@selector(showAlarm:)
                          userInfo:alarm repeats:NO];
```

which creates a timer and immediately schedules it.

Comment: +1 for being both correct and thorough! (Actually, I have to wait until midnight to upvote -- I've used my day's suppy already.)

Answer (score 2):

Well you may want to actually schedule your [`NSTimer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) on the run loop :) instead of `timerWithTimeInterval` use `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`.

```
theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:seconds 
                        target:self 
                      selector:@selector(showAlarm:)
                      userInfo:alarm repeats:NO];
```

Answer (score 2):

While all of the answers are right, there is an even simpler solution that doesn't involve a `NSTimer` at all. Your `setTimerForAlarm:` implementation can be reduced to one simple line:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(showAlarm:) withObject:alarm afterDelay:[[alarm alarmDate] timeIntervalSinceNow]]
```

Comment: Thanks, but NSTimer is the better choice at this point, because I also want to cancel the Timer anytime. :-)

Comment: You can also cancel a `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` with `+[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:]`

Comment: Thank you for this post! It's a massive time saver and my code is more compact.